# VBA how to fill in search bar with ID?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Web page has the following HTML without an ID - how do I set the value of the form?

```
<input name="loanxFindBorrower" onkeypress="if((window.event&amp;&amp;window.event.keyCode==13) || 
(event.which&amp;&amp;event.which==13 )){ findByBorrowerAction()}" type="text" size="25" value="">
```

I've tried

```
 IE.Document.getElementByTagName("loanxFindBorrower").Value = "New Value"
```

Aswell as

```
IE.Document.getElementByTagName("loanxFindBorrower").Focus
IE.Document.getElementByTagName("loanxFindBorrower").Value = "NewValue"
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getElementsByName()` to get the element. It returns a collection, you'll need to specify the index to get the element you want.

For example, if it's the first element with name "loanxFindBorrower" in the page, the index is 0:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByName("loanxFindBorrower")(0).Value = "New Value"
```

Comment: Hi @VBAutomate1308 May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.